# Diferenciar input vazio de input com valor 0

Tags: javascript

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo um pequeno projeto que calcula alguns movimentos da física, como movimento uniforme, circular etc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O intuito é calcular em tempo real, ou seja, após o usuário digitar em uma lacuna, se possível, o programa completa as outras automaticamente, calculando. Porém quando se digita algo e depois apaga, deixando-a vazia, ele entende que o valor daquela lacuna é 0, e não precisa mais completá-la, pois já foi fornecida (o programa entende que está vazia e precisa ser calculada quando é == undefined).

Eu poderia fazer um código dizendo que, quando o input for 0, ele recebe undefined, porém, quando o usuário realmente quiser fornecer o valor 0, o programa vai achar que precisa calcular aquela lacuna, quando na verdade não precisa :P

Existe uma maneira de diferenciar um input vazio de um input com valor 0?

Answer (score 0):

O tipo do valor de um input é sempre uma string, portanto um input não preenchido irá possuir `''`, enquanto um input preenchido com *0* irá possuir `'0'`.

O fato de você não estar conseguindo diferenciar uma string vazia de uma string com *0* me faz acreditar que você está convertendo essa string para um valor numérico antes mesmo de verificar se ela está vazia, e como `Number('')` resulta em *0*, você de fato não conseguirá diferenciar esses dois valores com essa abordagem.

Então basicamente você precisa verificar se o valor do seu input não é igual a `''` antes de converte-lo para um valor numérico.

Comment: Issso! Muito obrigado, deu certo!